# How to return a static array pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, static

I'm trying to create a function that creates a bidimensional array with default values. And then, the function should return the pointer for that static array.

```
int* novoTabuleiro() {

    static int *novoTabuleiro[LINHAS][COLUNAS];

    //Some changes

    return novoTabuleiro;
}
```

And then I want to do something like this:

```
int *tabuleiroJogador = novoTabuleiro();
```

What is wrong in the function above. The error I receive is "return from incompatible pointer type". Thanks.

Comment: `pointer to a static array`.. where's that?

Comment: I forget the static keyword, but the error keeps.

Comment: do you definitely want an array of pointers to int (not an array of ints) ?

Comment: To return a static array, first declare a static array.

Comment: No, what I really want is the array of ints.

Comment: @HenriqueDias in your code you have `static int *`... which means an array of pointers to int.

Comment: `return &novoTabuleiro[0][0];` ... int **tabuleiroJogador = novoTabuleiro();

Comment: That function looks like a global variable in disguise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comments indicate that the array is meant to be a 2-D array of ints:

```
static int novoTabuleiro[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
return novoTabuleiro;
```

Due to array-pointer decay, the expression `novoTabuleiro` in the return statement means the same as `&novoTabuleiro[0]`.

The type of `novoTabuleiro[0]` is "array [COLUNAS] of int" , i.e. `int [COLUNAS]`.  So a pointer to this is `int (*)[COLUNAS]`.

That means your function needs to be:

```
int (*func())[COLUNAS]  {
```

and the calling code would be:

```
int (*tabuleiroJogador)[COLUNAS] = func();
```

It would be less confusing to use a different name for the function than you use for the name of the array within the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off use `std::array`

```
static std::array<std::array<int, LINHAS>, COLUNAS> novoTabuleiro;
return novoTabuleiro;
```