# Return static array from my object

Tags: c++, arrays, static

Having

```
class Foo {
public:
  static constexpr size_t WIDTH = 10;
  static constexpr size_t HEIGHT = 20;

private:
  int _data[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
}
```

I would to get my variable _data from a member function of this class, but I cant find the good prototype.

see @[How to return a static array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399577/how-to-return-a-static-array-pointer)
but this syntax seems to dont work with member functions, it can't compile.
Also tried

```
int **getData() {
  return static_cast<int **>(_data);
}
```

But I dont think this is a good pratice.

Comment: cause it's useless to create an object for my case :") it's kinda related to optimizations, but that's not rly the question, Im kinda sure we can return this static array with some syntax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always return a pointer to the first element, like you did which is perfectly safe.

The better solution IMO would be to use `std::array`, which *can* be copied unlike C style arrays.

Another way would be to return a reference to the array:

```
auto& getData() { return _data; }
```

Without `auto` it would look like this:

```
int (&get())[HEIGHT][WIDTH] { return _data; }
```

You can always make it pretty with `using`:

```
using RefToArray = int(&)[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
RefToArray get() { return _data; }
```

Comment: this cant compile by the way >< I though at start.. Is it compiling on your computer?

Comment: @lordjj Yes it does (see for example [here](https://godbolt.org/g/hep3S5)). What did you do differently and/or what's the error?

Comment: @lordjj Oh wait, you need C++14 for this. Which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: It does compile, but when I call the function getData(), this comes out: use of ‘auto& GameMap::getData() const’ before deduction of ‘auto’. The instance of the concerned GameMap is already created, it justs break the compilation when I try to call getData()

Comment: I'm using C++ 17

Comment: Ah well, that's because you can't declare it because it returns auto. You can define it inline (inside the class definition immediately) or write out the type without using auto, but that would make the function unreadable IMO.

Comment: it could be interesting to know the syntax if u know it :) (without auto)